# Foreign key with composite primary key not working in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, ddl

I have the following SQL script.  After it runs the foreign key relationship is never enforced.

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
  name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  abbreviation varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (name)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE StateProvince (
  countryName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  abbreviation varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (countryName,name)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

alter table StateProvince
add index FK_StateProvince_Country (countryName),
add constraint FK_StateProvince_Country
foreign key (countryName)
references Country (name);
```

Is this because of the composite primary key?

Comment: Why have you used CountryName as composite primary key and foreign key in the stateprovince table. Is it not better to use CountryName as a foreign key alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL docs on foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html), The MyISAM table engine does not support foreign keys. Instead it silently ignores them. Use InnoDB instead. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
  name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  abbreviation varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE StateProvince (
  countryName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  abbreviation varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (countryName,name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

alter table StateProvince
add index FK_StateProvince_Country (countryName),
add constraint FK_StateProvince_Country
foreign key (countryName)
references Country (name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the InnoDB engine supports [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB supports foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It had nothing to do with that, as per this article

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html

> A foreign key constraint is not
>   required merely to join two tables.
>   **For storage engines other than InnoDB,**
>   it is possible when defining a column
>   to use a REFERENCES tbl_name(col_name)
>   clause, which has no actual effect,
>   and serves only as a memo or comment
>   to you that the column which you are
>   currently defining is intended to
>   refer to a column in another table. It
>   is extremely important to realize when
>   using this syntax that:

Answer (score 0):

@Benju.

You have to replace MyISAM with InnoDB and then you can use Primary key as a composite or single. It works and i have tested.